# Is it possible to auto adjust line's width between text in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw line between text and adjust line's width so that it does not overflow to next line.

```
\begin{document}
AAAAAAAAAAA\tikz\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (4,0);BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB \tikz\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (4,0); CCCCCCCCCCCCCC 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to draw these lines, you do not need Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\begin{document}
AAAAAAAAAAA\xrfill[0pt]{0.4pt}[blue]BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\xrfill[0pt]{0.4pt}[blue]CCCCCCCCCCCCCC 
\end{document}
```

[image]